# I want to get/print df by range instead of head or tail

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I can't find or understand how to get the data I want by range
I want to know how to get df['Close']from x to y then .mean to sum it up

I have tried "costomclose = df['Close'],range(dagartot,val)"
But it gives me something else like heads and tails from df

```
if len(df) >= 34:
        dagartot = len(df)
        valdagar = 5
        val = dagartot-valdagar
        costomclose = df['Close'],range(dagartot,val)
        print(costomclose)
```

edit:

```
<bound method NDFrame.tail of                   High         Low  ...    Volume   Adj Close
Date                                ...                      
2005-09-29   24.083300   23.583300  ...   74400.0    4.038682
2005-09-30   23.833300   23.500000  ...  148200.0    4.081495
2005-10-03   24.000000   23.333300  ...   27600.0    3.995869
2005-10-04   23.500000   23.416700  ...  132000.0    4.024417
2005-10-05   23.750000   23.500000  ...   15600.0    4.067230
...                ...         ...  ...       ...         ...
2019-07-25  196.000000  193.050003  ...  355952.0  194.000000
2019-07-26  196.350006  194.000000  ...  320752.0  195.199997
2019-07-29  196.350006  193.550003  ...  301389.0  195.250000
2019-07-30  197.949997  194.850006  ...  233989.0  197.100006
2019-07-31  198.550003  195.600006  ...  323473.0  197.899994

[3479 rows x 6 columns]>
```

stop

Comment: You mean you want the df values from X to Y? Use `df.iloc[x:y]`

Comment: Thanks, but I cant get that to work. I only get 
(Empty DataFrame
Columns: [High, Low, Open, Close, Volume, Adj Close]
Index: [], ['Close'])
stop

this back

Comment: Post a copy of your df (preferably in a machine-readable form, like the output of `df.to_dict()`).

Comment: That gives me nothing, but df.tail gives me this Look my edit

Comment: df = pd.read_csv(folderpick + '/' + johansfilename + '.csv', parse_dates=True, index_col=0)

Comment: Try `df.to_dict('records')`. You didn't invoke `df.tail`.

Comment: IIUC, what you might need is some rolling window calculation.

Comment: I don't have your folder or the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of slicing out the middle of a dataframe that stores the alphabet:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([dict(num=i + 65, char=chr(i + 65))  for i in range(26)])
>>> df[(76 <= df.num) & (df.num < 81)]
    num char
11   76    L
12   77    M
13   78    N
14   79    O
15   80    P
```

Comment: Thanks for help, I'm to low level at programming to follow what your trying to show me sorry. I have my df already.

Comment: Your inaccessible .CSV file interfered with producing a minimal complete question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Details of your particular dataset were irrelevant to the question at hand. I offered twenty-six example rows that anyone could easily reproduce, then illustrated the syntax you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of slicing out the middle of something based on the encounter index:

```
>>> s = pd.Series(list('abcdefghijklmnop'))

>>> s
Out[135]: 
0     a
1     b
...
12    m
13    n
14    o
15    p
dtype: object

>>> s.iloc[6:9]
Out[136]: 
6    g
7    h
8    i
dtype: object
```

This also works for DataFrames, e.g. `df.iloc[0]` returns the first row and `df.iloc[5:8]` returns those rows, end not included.

You can also slice by actual index of the DataFrame, which is not necessarily a serially-counting sequence of integers by substituting `iloc` for `loc`.